# How to get full url of a article by it's ID in joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have article id, How can I get valid full url of this article? This article already associated with menu but I might not know, is there any easy way in php to get **url**? I am using joomla 3.2
I tried following already.

```
$article = ControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content')->getModel('Article')->getItem($article‌​Id); 
JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($articleId,$article->catid))
```

Comment: `
$article = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content')->getModel('Article')->getItem($articleId);
JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($articleId,$article->catid))`
It dont work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use like this

```
 $article = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content')
            ->getModel('Article')->getItem($articleId);

  $url =  JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($articleId, 
                      $article->catid, 
                      $article->language))
```

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this because I think this information is useful to all other users who want full current URL anywhere in Joomla not only in articles.

In Joomla use `JURI`class to get URLs.
Functions like `root()`, `current()` & `base()` will be used according to the need.

```
echo 'Joomla root URI is ' . JURI::root();
output:-Joomla root URI is http://localhost/joomla/

echo 'Joomla current URI is ' . JURI::current();
output:-Joomla current URI is http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/somealias
```

Note:- `current()` will give the whole URI except the query string part, for example,

IF your full URL is http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/somealias?id=1 then `current()` will only return this-> `http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/somealias`

While, if you use `JURI::getInstance()->toString()` then it will return this->

http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/somealias?id=1

For more information see these links->

1. https://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root
2. https://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current
3. https://docs.joomla.org/JURI/getInstance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [JURI](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current) (from Joomla! API) help you:

exemple:

```
echo 'Joomla current URI is ' . JURI::current() . "\n";
```

might output

```
Joomla base URI is http://localhost/joomla/
```

- [JURI class](http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JURI.html)

Comment: Did you really read the question? I need url of article by it's id. not joomla url

Comment: I don't think insulting somebody trying to help you is going to get your poorly formatted question answered.

Comment: I did not insult anybody, just suggest people not to answered if they really did not read the question, i mean title of question. I am also surprise with your negative rating of question. people come here to ask only after they did not find the right answer on web easily

Comment: @user2737980 I answered based on what I could understand. The solution I posted is one of the ways to get to what you want.